# Scala comparing type:Ordering

Tags: scala, types, compare

I have a sorting function like this:

```
def sort[A:Ordering](vals: Array[A]):Array[A] = {
for (i <- 1 until vals.length) {
  val temp = vals(i)
  var j = i
  while (j > 0 && temp < vals(j-1) ){
    vals(j) = vals(j-1)
    j -= 1
  }
  vals(j) = temp;
}
vals
```

}

And its supposed to get an array of type A(which is either Int or String, but the code doesn't know that) as a parameter and sort it and then return it. 
Now eclipse tells me that:

"value < is not a member of type parameter A"

at line 5. I don´t understand why can't it compare those values, I've tried A:Comparable, A:Ordered and A:every-word-that-could-possibly-work. Nothing works.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[A:Ordering]` on a function `sort` means that *there should exist such implicit value (to be completely honest it may not be implicit, but in this case you'll have to pass it by manually), that has type `Ordering[A]` at the point of `sort` call, and this implicit value will be added in separate argument list of the function*.

This is how [typeclasses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class) supported in Scala.

This won't magically add `<` to `A`, as there is no type bound on `A` and compiller can know no more that `A` is a subtype of `Any`.

Anyway, to use ordering in body of your `sort` you can obtain it using:

```
implicitly[Ordering[A]]
```

... and then use it. This works because, again implicit value of type `Ordering[A]` were added behind the scenes in extra argument list of `sort`.

Here is a code snippet that should give you an idea on how to use it in your code:

```
scala> def lt[T : Ordering](a: T, b: T) = { implicitly[Ordering[T]].lt(a, b) }
lt: [T](a: T, b: T)(implicit evidence$1: Ordering[T])Boolean

scala> lt(1, 1)
res9: Boolean = false

scala> lt(1, 2)
res10: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I would've never figured out something like that! Now in other part of my code I have this: var arr = Array.ofDim[A](size) and it says "no ClassTag avaible for A". Does this have something to do with the solution above?

Comment: @OuTsei that's another issue. Google info on `ClassTag`s and how to deal with type erasure in Scala.

Comment: I still can't get it to work. I tried, among other failures, this: var arr = Array.ofDim[Ordering[A]](size) and eclipse seems to be okay with that but its the wrong type. arr should be Array[A]